# The Properties Shelf is empty after scrolling over the area. How can I remedy that?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm using shelf transparency but I hope you can see the Shelf and that it is absent of anything. It happened when I was scrolling over the shelf unintentionally. I'm using the latest daily build of 2.79

[image]

Comment: You can scroll to top with `Home`, or scroll manually by middle click + dragging, but the absence of a scrollbar makes me suspect it really is empty. Is it consistently like this? If so, does it still happen with factory settings?

Comment: I did reset Blender to the factory defaults and nothing changed. What did work was copying and pasting the model into a new document

Comment: Solved. You mentioned the Home key and I have a Mac, so I started randomly playing with arrow keys while holding down the function key and... voila! the Shelf returned to normal. Thanks for taking the time to answer.